# any Guide path to learn PlayFramework for Java

Tags: playframework-2.0

there is no guided documentation available for Play(java). Can any one give me a link or something that shows how to do things in play. I have checked the documentation on the official site but it is bare minimal and not to explanatory.

I really like this framework and would love to develop my new project in Play. But right now it is not like anything I have worked on earlier so it is all very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh c'mon there are some useful resources :)

- First you have [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Home) - traverse the Getting started - that's good point to start
- There is also step-by-step tutorial describing how to create [Your first application](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTodoList).
- Finally, examine samples delivered with Play sources - you can run every and check how it works, you can test what happens, when you changes code. You'll find there apps for most typical uses.

Comment: Do not forget to mention the [book](http://www.manning.com/leroux/), and the [community section](http://www.playframework.org/community) on the play framework website.

Comment: @adis you are welcome to edit my post :) (or write another answer)

Comment: I have been to all of the above links, But still I am not able to understand how things are done in play. I think I have to buy the book. 

One more thing. are there things which can not be done in java version but can be done in scala version. Please guide if play with scala is more powerful then play for java.